# JSSOR slider: several images visible

Tags: jssor

I am looking for a way to make the JSSOR slider show several, e.g. three, images at once, and for each slide movement (auto, arrows, navigator buttons), I want it to shift only one image at a time. Attached is an image to best illustrate what I want. [image: three-image slider]

I tried the `$DisplayPieces: 1` option but even after setting it to 3, still only one image shows, and the slider isn't disabled as the warning says.

If I try to change the size of `slider_container`, e.g. set it to 900px, it does not change - instead, the image inside gets smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display multi slides, you'd set $SlideWidth manually, and adjust size of 'slides' container to display more than one slides.

For example (display 3 slides),

```
var options = {
    ...
    $SlideWidth: 150,
    $DisplayPieces: 3,
    ...
};

<div id="slider1_container" style="... width: 450px; ...">
    <div u="slides" style=" ... width: 450px; ...">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually found one site showing the example code for something similar: [link]http://cgit.drupalcode.org/zircon/tree/jssor/demo/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.source.html?id=ac7eecbf4daf8abe7fbcc76b80205565d9db9a7d. What I was missing was changing the `$SlideWidth` parameter was required as well. I figured, however, that if I use the 3-image slider, responsiveness becomes more difficult, that is, the already small images will look too small to be useful.